# The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime (Formatting)

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime, textbox

I am trying to convert a Oracle `DateTime` field into a string (`TextBox`).  However I keep getting the following error:

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The value in the field is: `7/25/2013 4:12:18 PM`

Code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",dr["category"].ToString().Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
txtFedCat.Text = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
```

Comment: The captial `HH` implies 24 hour I'm pretty sure..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["category"].ToString().Trim(), "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The first parameter to ParseExact is the date string, and the second, the format. You had it the other way around.
Also I think you want to use the following format specifiers:

- M : The month, from 1 through 12.
- d : The day of the month, from 1 through 31.
- h : The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12.

Comment: Fi fcuesta, thanks for the help.  I tried your solution but I am still getting the same error: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'

Comment: Ignore my previous comment.  There was something wrong with my SQL statement that was causing the error after I added your code.  Your answer was right. Thanks!

Comment: what is the meaning of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ??

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateString = "7/25/2013 4:12:18 PM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var txtFedCat = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
string strDate = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateTime, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null).ToString();
        if (strDate.Substring(0, 10).Trim().LastIndexOf(" ", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) == 8)
            strDate = strDate.Substring(0, 8).Trim();
        else
            strDate = strDate.Substring(0, 10).Trim();
        DateTime FinalDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);
```

Comment: Please elaborate why the problem occured and what does this code do.